# sqlite3_prepare_v2 depends on scope

Tags: c++, sqlite

i use sqlite3_prepare_v2 within c++ application and get memory leaks, when instantiate a
sqlite3_stmt outside function which is calling sqlite3_prepare_v2.

sample:

```
sqlite3_stmt* ps=NULL;
void prepare(void)
{
   if(ps == NULL)
       sqlite3_prepare_v2(&db,"insert into nomatterbd...",-1,&ps,NULL);

}
```

call prepare, close application and you get memory leaks.

Doing this way:

```
void prepare(void)
{
  sqlite3_stmt* ps=NULL;
  sqlite3_prepare_v2(&db,"insert into nomatterbd...",-1,&ps,NULL);
}
```

no memory leaks.
checked with latest amalgation.

My goal is to open and close a DB on each insert or update. To speed up the whole
thing, i'd like to prepare global statements for insert and update.
Unfortunately, this will fail, if global and once created statements cause mem leaks.

Can anyone help ? Thank you.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a **complete** program that demonstrates your problem. Please keep it **short** (20 lines or less is perfect). Please copy-paste it directly into the question so that we can compile it and see if we get the same results. See: http://sscce.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling sqlite3_finalize()?

http://sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html

Your question does not state when the memory leak occurs - I am guessing when the program exits.

Comment: yes, finalized is called. In both cases. Forgott to add to code sample.

Comment: Well, its hard to guess what your mem leak is, when your code sample is missing important parts!

Comment: i am sorry for lag of code. I do a release and the leaks are shown in debug dump when closing (VS2008). The first code sample does leak. The 2nd does not. The first sample uses a global statement the 2nd not.